# Valgrind Warning: Should I Take It Seriously

Tags: c, valgrind, overlap, strcpy

Background:
I have a small routine that mimics `fgets(character, 2, fp)` except it takes a character from a string instead of a stream. newBuff is dynamically allocated string passed as a parameter and character is declared as `char character[2]`.

Routine:

```
character[0] = newBuff[0];

character[1] = '\0';

strcpy(newBuff, newBuff+1);
```

The strcpy replicates the loss of information as each character is read from it.

> Problem:  Valgrind does warns me about
>   this activity, "Source and destination
>   overlap in strcpy(0x419b818,
>   0x419b819)".

Should I worry about this  warning?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Probably the standard does not specify what happens when these buffers overlap.  So yes, `valgrind` is right to complain about this.

In practical terms you will most likely find that *your* `strcpy` copies in order from left-to-right (eg. `while (*dst++ = *src++);`) and that it's not an issue.  But it it still incorrect and may have issues when running with other C libraries.

One standards-correct way to write this would be:

```
memmove(newBuff, newBuff+1, strlen(newBuff));
```

Because `memmove` is defined to handle overlap.  (Although here you would end up traversing the string twice, once to check the length and once to copy.  I also took a shortcut, since `strlen(newBuff)` should equal `strlen(newBuff+1)+1`, which is what I originally wrote.)

Comment: Even if the ordering is left-to-right, there could be issues due to unrolling/reordering and larger-than-byte units of copying. I would consider this usage of `strcpy` highly unsafe and likely to break even between different versions of the same library, or even different builds with different compilers.

Comment: @R.. I agree, especially with the point about larger-than-byte units.  Just to be clear, I agree that the code is incorrect and should be changed.

Comment: I think what you originally wrote, `strlen(newBuff+1)+1`, is better. It should be in your code, because it's readable. It should be on Stackoverflow, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, and you should also worry that your function has pathologically bad performance (`O(n^2)` for a task that should be `O(n)`). Moving the entire contents of the string back by a character every time you read a character is a huge waste of time. Instead you should just keep a pointer to the current position and increment that pointer.

Situations where you find yourself needing `memmove` or the equivalent (copying between buffers that overlap) *almost always* indicate a design flaw. Often it's not just a flaw in the implementation but in the *interface*.

Answer (score 4):

Yes -- the behavior of `strcpy` is only defined if the source and dest don't overlap. You might consider a combination of `strlen` and `memmove` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you should worry.  The C standard states that the behavior of `strcpy` is [undefined](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html) when the source and destination objects overlap.    Undefined behavior means it may work sometimes, or it may fail, or it may appear to succeed but manifest failure elsewhere in the program.

Answer (score 3):

The behavior of `strcpy()` is officially undefined if source and destination overlap.

From the manpage for memcpy comes a suggestion:

> The memcpy() function copies n bytes from memory area s2 to memory area s1.  If s1 and s2 overlap, behavior is undefined.  Applications in which s1 and s2 might overlap should use memmove(3) instead.

Comment: Regardless of how it's implemented, the behavior is undefined. This is stated explicitly in the standard.

Comment: `strcpy` gives undefined behavior if the buffers overlap. `memcpy` does the same, but is otherwise irrelevant.

Comment: OK, my local man page for strcpy doesn't contain that warning, but the memcpy one does.

Comment: The only functions in the C standard that accept pointers to overlapping memory regions for reading and writing are `memmove` and `wmemmove`. For everything else (including `snprintf`!) the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is yes: with certain compiler/library implementations, newest ones I guess, you'll end up with a bogus result. See [How is strcpy implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12935371/how-is-strcpy-implemented) for an example.